# Request payload mysteriously not set when submitting form second time: AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Desperately need another set of eyes. This form submission works perfectly on the first submission. But unless I reload the page again it fails. I feel like I've checked everything, the form values are reset fine no matter what in the js but for some reason they do not make it into the Request payload on the second post. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
$scope.submitLogin = function(data) {
  var form = $scope.login;
  $scope.formerror = '';
  $scope.success = '';
  if (form.username.length > 0 &&
    form.password.length > 0) {
    console.log(form.username);
    console.log(form.password);
    $http.post('/login', form)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.success = data['res'];
        $scope.login = [];
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        $scope.formerror = data;
      });

  } else {
    $scope.formerror = "something went wrong. Try again.";
  }
  //$scope.form = new Array({'error':'test', 'msg':''});
}
```

```html
<form id="login-form" ng-submit="submitLogin()" role="form">

  <label for="login_user">username: </label>
  <input id="login_user" ng-model="login.username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">


  <label for="login_password">password: </label>
  <input id="login_password" ng-model="login.password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">

  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="login">

</form>
```

Comment: Does you console show values for username/password in your second POST?

Comment: It does. That's what's so strange.

Comment: I figured it out. It was just because I was setting the form array to an empty array [] after success on post. I changed that to setting each form value individually to an empty string and now I am getting expected behavior. Thank you all for any effort.